# JQuery-UI draggable elements appear on top of others when they are dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using JQuery-UI to be able to drag items from one div to another, but when I drop the element in another div, it appears on top of other dropped elements. What am I doing wrong?

```
        //These are my draggable elements
        $('#interface li').draggable({
            helper: 'clone',
            revert: 'invalid'
        });

        //This function makes dropped elements draggable again.
        function foo(){
            $('.foo').each(function() {
                $(this).draggable({
                    containment: $(this).parent(),
                    stack: '.foo'
                });
            });
        }

        //This function forms table around dropped item
        var fooCount = $('.foo').length;
        $('#mainDiv').droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('foo')) {
                    var Class = ui.draggable.attr("class");
                    var title = ui.draggable.text().trim();
                    var item = $('<table class="foo elementTable ' + Class + '" name="' + title + '" id="'+(fooCount+1)+'"><tr class="tableHeader"><th class="thClass"><button class="settings">set</button>' + title + '<span class="close">x</span></th></tr><tr><td class="add"><span class="addList">Add new link</span></td></tr></table>');
                    $(this).append(item);
                    fooCount += 1;
                    foo();
                }
            }
        });
```

This is my CSS code for styling newly created tables:

```
.foo {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
}
```

But the dropped elements appear like this:

[image]

I want them to appear like this:

[image]

EDIT: Here is a working jsfiffle: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/79kd1uLL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `position: absolute;` from newly created element. It should be

```
.foo {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    padding: 0;
}
```

Check updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/79kd1uLL/1/)

Comment: I have tried, but everything gets totally messed up. After dropping I must be able to drag them, create endpoints, connections, add new links and so on. If I remove positioning, nothing works properly.

Comment: I have added jsfiddle. my code is really complex and I did not include all the functionality that my app has, but everything needed is here.

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: just remove `position: absolute`

Comment: Yes, it works correctly, but until I add jsplumb endpoints and connectors. Then everything get messed up again. I'll try to set position: inherit while creating table and I'll remove this property after drop.

Comment: It didn't yet. I'll upvote it, because it helped me to find a problem, but I can't accept it until I won't fix it.